# How to escape Salesforce search query

Tags: rest-api, rest, ruby-on-rails

I'm using the [Salesforce ruby gem](https://github.com/ejholmes/restforce) to do the following

```
@client.search("FIND {#{@email}}")
```

`@email` returns the user's email address. During testing, I had an email address like `test+test@example.com` and this caused a MALFORMED_SEARCH error. I tried calling `to_json` on the email, but that didn't fix it. What kind of escaping should I be doing here? Is there a generic way to do this?

I'd like to avoid escaping specific characters like '+', but if that's necessary, I understand. I just don't know what that list of invalid characters is.

I guess a more specific question is: how do I make sure that any query I pass into FIND won't return a MALFORMED_SEARCH error because of invalid characters or something like that?

Thanks!

[EDIT] It seems that the plus sign is the only issue here... Is there any documentation that enumerates other symbols that might be an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` symbol is reserved in SOQL, this is covered in the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_sosl_find.htm) along with the other reserved characters:

> The following characters are reserved:
> `? & | ! { } [ ] ( ) ^ ~ * : \ " ' + -`
>
> Reserved characters, if specified in a text search, must be escaped (preceded by the backslash \ character) in order to be properly interpreted. An error occurs if you do not precede reserved characters with a backslash. This is true even if the `SearchQuery` is enclosed in double quotes.